# Using an Array of Strings to Determine Show/Hide

Tags: jquery, arrays, class, loops, object

I have a javascript object containing multiple arrays. I'm using `classes` and `click events` to identify what is clicked, and to use the object to tell the DOM what to display.

The object in question looks like this (simplified):

```
  var inputSelection = {
    account : ["registration","password"],
    device : ["forceStop","clearData"]
  };
```

And let's pretend we have HTML as such:

```
<div id="reasonDiv"><fieldset><legend>Reason</legend>
      <label class="account"><input type="checkbox">Account<br /></label>
      <label class="device"><input type="checkbox" />Device<br />
</div>
<div id="context"><fieldset><legend>Context</legend>
      <label class="clearData"><input type="checkbox">Clear Data<br /></label>
      <label class="forceStop"><input type="checkbox" />Force Stop<br />
      <label class="registration"><input type="checkbox">Registration<br /></label>
      <label class="password"><input type="checkbox" />Password<br /></label></fieldset>
</div>
```

In essence, I want to be able to find all of the values within the `account` array of the object when **Account** is clicked.

Alternatively access the values within the `device` array when **Device** is clicked.

I've tried this particular code:

```
  $('#reasonDiv label').on('click', function(){
    node1 = $(this).attr('class');
    $.each( inputSelection[node1], function( intValue, currentElement ) {
      $('div#context').each('label', function(){
        if($(this).attr('class') === currentElement){
          $(this).show();
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

I think I'm just nesting the `each` function incorrectly, as I keep getting this weird error in `console` saying:

```
TypeError: c.apply is not a function @ jquery.min.js:2
```

The goal is to click on a checkbox, and display any items that contain *any* classes in the associated array.

What am I missing here?

http://jsfiddle.net/66y3E/1/

Comment: An error in the jQuery file usually means you've got a syntax error in the code you wrote.

Comment: Yeah, it appears the callback is failing when I'm nesting two .each statements. I just can't seem to find out where to nail it down...

Comment: I would suggest always closing your HTML tags for easier troubleshooting and reading (as it lets code formatters do their thing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/73v48/1/

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    var node1;

    $('#reasonDiv input').on('click', function() {
        var anyChecked = false;
        $('#reasonDiv input').each(function() {
            var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');

            anyChecked |= isChecked;
            node1 = $(this).attr('class');
            console.log($(this), isChecked);

            if (isChecked) {
                $('.data-'+node1).show();
            } else {
                $('.data-'+node1).hide();
            }
        });

        if (anyChecked) {
            $('#context').show();
        } else {
            $('#context').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

We can accomplish this just by using classes instead of an associative array.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Actually I just named the classes prefixed with `data-`, not to be confused with `data` attributes. I think using data attributes may be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML was a bit of a mess with events firing multiple times due to mal-formed tags.  Also you were using the wrong type of comparator. `===` won't work.

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/TJF65/

HTML:

```
<div id="reasonDiv">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Reason For Contact</legend>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <label class="account">Account</label>
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <label class="device">Device</label>
        <br />
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div id="context">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Context</legend>
        <div class="clearData">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <label>Clear Data</label>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="forceStop">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <label>Force Stop</label>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="registration">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <label>Registration</label>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="password">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <label>Password</label>
        </div>
        <br />
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 var inputSelection = {
        account: ["registration", "password"],
        device: ["forceStop", "clearData"]
    };
    var node1;

    $('#reasonDiv label').on('click', function (event) {
        console.log(event);
        node1 = $(this).attr('class');
        $.each(inputSelection[node1], function (intValue, currentElement) {
            $('div#context div').each(function () {
                if ($(this).attr('class') == currentElement) {
                    $(this).show();
                    console.log('showing');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since inputSelection is a regular array, search it with a for loop rather than .each

```
$('#reasonDiv label').on('click', function(){
    //the following code would not allow multiple classes on the element
    var node1 = $(this).attr('class');
    var arr = inputSelection[node1];

    //note: you likely need some logic here to hide existing elements

    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        var currentElement = arr[i];
        //convert currentElement into a selector
        $('div#context').find("."+currentElement).show();
    }
});
```

Another suggestion, consider making use of your input fields to provide the value for your 
search.

```
<div id="reasonDiv"><fieldset><legend>Reason</legend>
  <label class="account"><input name="search" type="radio" value="Account">Account<br /></label>
  <label class="device"><input name="search" type="radio" value="Device"/>Device<br />
</div>

var node1 = $("input[name=search]:checked").val();
```